# UWP themes and styles: Highcontrast theme not using the correct colors

Tags: c#, uwp, themes, accessibility

My app is running with the "Light" built in theme.

Whenever I switch to another highcontrast theme while my app is running, some colors get incorrect values.

For example when i switch from no theme to HighContrastBlack while my app is running, i get the colors defined in HighContrastWhite...

When i restart the app after switching themes in the Windows settings, there's no problem.

It happens only with brushes that are not using a ThemeResource as color. For example the FileExplorerBorderBrush.

References are made to the brushes by using "ThemeResource" instead of "StaticResource", so this also can't be the problem

App.xaml:

```
<Application
x:Class="My_App.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:My_App"
RequestedTheme="Light">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/SplitViewStyles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/PageStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

PageStyles.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:My_App.Styles">

<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PageBackgroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource PageBackgroundColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueAccentColorBrush" Color="{ThemeResource BlueAccentColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OrangeAccentColorBrush" Color="{ThemeResource OrangeAccentColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LabelTextColorBrush" Color="{ThemeResource LabelTextColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppHeaderColorBrush" Color="{ThemeResource BlueAccentColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FileExplorerBorderBrush" Color="{ThemeResource BlueAccentColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PaneBackgroundBrush" Color="WhiteSmoke" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SettingsPageBackgroundBrush" Color="White" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopBarDividerLineBrush" Color="#3a3a3a" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrastCustom">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PageBackgroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueAccentColorBrush" Color="Blue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OrangeAccentColorBrush" Color="Orange" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LabelTextColorBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowTextColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppHeaderColorBrush" Color="Blue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FileExplorerBorderBrush" Color="Blue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PaneBackgroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SettingsPageBackgroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopBarDividerLineBrush" Color="Blue" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrastBlack">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PageBackgroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueAccentColorBrush" Color="Blue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OrangeAccentColorBrush" Color="Orange" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LabelTextColorBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowTextColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppHeaderColorBrush" Color="Blue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FileExplorerBorderBrush" Color="Yellow" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PaneBackgroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SettingsPageBackgroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopBarDividerLineBrush" Color="Yellow" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrastWhite">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PageBackgroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueAccentColorBrush" Color="Blue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OrangeAccentColorBrush" Color="Orange" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LabelTextColorBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowTextColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppHeaderColorBrush" Color="Blue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FileExplorerBorderBrush" Color="Blue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PaneBackgroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SettingsPageBackgroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TopBarDividerLineBrush" Color="Blue" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

Comment: The most common high contrast bug is caused by hard-coding a color on a control inline. Don't use hard code a color in the HighContrast theme; use the SystemColor*Color resources. See [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/accessibility/high-contrast-themes?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#high-contrast-colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/accessibility/high-contrast-themes?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#high-contrast-colors)